# pyspark apply schema to csv - returns only null values

Tags: csv, pyspark, schema, databricks

I have many "wide" csv files (100+ columns) in a directory. I think I have read somewhere that by applying a schema I can already preselect the columns which should be read. Unfortunately my code only returns "NULL"´s.

Does somebody know if my assumption with the "schema" is wrong? The path in the read-statment in the code below is ok.

Here is the code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

DCU_schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("consistId", T.StringType(), True),
  T.StructField("subsystemId", T.StringType(), True),
  T.StructField("E13", T.BooleanType(), True),
  T.StructField("E40", T.BooleanType(), True),
  T.StructField("Strom_links", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("Strom_rechts", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("Spannung_links", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("Spannung_rechts", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("Position_links", T.IntegerType(), True),
  T.StructField("Position_rechts", T.IntegerType(), True),
  T.StructField("canTimeStamp", T.LongType(), True),
  T.StructField("latitude", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("longitude", T.DoubleType(), True),
  T.StructField("fileName", T.StringType(), True)
])

first_kb_df = (spark.read.csv(path=path, schema=DCU_schema, inferSchema=False, header=True, sep=";")
              .orderBy("canTimeStamp"))
display(first_kb_df)
```

Attached is also a screenshot of the result.

Thanks in advance for your help and best regards
Alex

[Screenshot of Returned Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InP1e.png)

[Screenshot of Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM0HX.png)

Comment: add some sample input data..?

Comment: can you do head over the input file?

Comment: input file with inferSchema=True and Header=True -> see new screenshot in original post

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft Documentation

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("_c0",IntegerType,true)
  .add("carat",DoubleType,true)
  .add("cut",StringType,true)
  .add("color",StringType,true)
  .add("clarity",StringType,true)
  .add("depth",DoubleType,true)
  .add("table",DoubleType,true)
  .add("price",IntegerType,true)
  .add("x",DoubleType,true)
  .add("y",DoubleType,true)
  .add("z",DoubleType,true)

val diamonds_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv")
```

Comment: Or your types are too much off the actual types. E.g. you are trying to convert a float (with . value in it) to an integer.

Comment: this is scala although not a problem; I  have found this already; the difference to my question is, that this schema includes "all" columns; I have 100+ columns and only need to read 14 of them; the types are 100% correct

Comment: With a schema that won't help. How i would do it is add a .select(*lCols) to it and put your desired columns in a list called lCols

Comment: Hi, but that does not solve the described problem to apply a predefined schema. What I have found is that with csv files it is not possible to apply a schema to a subset of the data. I have solved it now that I read.csv (inferSchema = False), select the columns (as you suggested) and then use withColumn("E13", F.col("E13").cast("boolean")) to get the desired Spark Type. Thanks for your comments and have a fine day